# the code is running fine on the web, but why am i getting null error?

Tags: javascript, html

index.html:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

the code run fine but why am i getting the above error?

i already tried running the script before and after the html element, still getting error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var txt1 = "some text else"; 
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var txt = document.write("some text here");
        document.getElementById('ii').innerHTML = txt; 
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="ii"></p>
<script>
    document.write(txt1);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The element with the id `ii` is not in the DOM at the time when you do `document.getElementById('ii')`

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is executed before the DOM has been loaded. Put all `<script>`-Tags just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: About `Your javascript is executed before the DOM has been loaded.`, if you place the `<script>` right before `</body>` then the DOM is - technically - still not fully loaded at the time the `document.getElementById('ii')` is exectued. To DOM is still only partially loaded, but it contains the `ii` element because the `<script>` tag is placed after the element with the id `ii`.